# How can I ensure that observe is called before renderPlot in my shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, observers

I have a shiny application with two selectInputs (L1 and L2) with an observer that updates L2 based on the selection of L1 using updateSelectInput.  I also have a renderPlot output that depends on both selections. The problem I face is that whenever I change L1, the renderPlot gets called twice, once with the old value of L2 and once with the new value (set in updateSelectInput).  My code is below:

```
ui.R
shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Nested Selects Problem"),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                selectInput(
                    "L1",
                    label = "L1",
                    choices = c("red", "blue")
                    ),
                selectInput(
                    "L2",
                    label = "L2",
                    choices = ""
                    )
                ),
            mainPanel(
                plotOutput("plot")
                )
            )
        )
    )

server.R
shinyServer(
    function(input,output,session) {
        observe({
            if (input$L1 == "red") {
                choices <- c(1000000,2000000,3000000)
            }
            else {
                choices <- c(10,20,30)
            }
            updateSelectInput(session,"L2",choices=choices,selected=choices[1])
        })

        output$plot <- renderPlot({
            if (input$L2 != "") {
                plot(runif(as.numeric(input$L2)),col=input$L1)
            }
        })
    })
```

How can I avoid the first call to renderPlot?  It seems to me that if I could arrange the observe() to be called before the first renderPlot, I would get the desired effect.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What about create a reactive value that will be updated in the observer? And in the renderPlot you can check the reactive value's state as well (if it is not satisfied, draws nothing). And since it's a reactive value, once it's changed, it will invalidate `renderPlot` hence trigger the redraw.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isolate` on the `input$L1` call inside `renderPlot`. In this manner the changes should propagate from your `updateSelectInput` call only when `input$L1` is changed :

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Nested Selects Problem"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("L1",label = "L1",choices = c("red", "blue")),
        selectInput("L2",label = "L2",choices = "")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot")
      )
    )
  )


  , server = function(input,output,session) {
    observe({
      if (input$L1 == "red") {
        choices <- c(100,200,300)
      }
      else {
        choices <- c(10,20,30)
      }
      updateSelectInput(session,"L2",choices=choices,selected=choices[1])
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      if (input$L2 != "") {
        plot(runif(as.numeric(input$L2)),col=isolate(input$L1))
      }
    })
  })
)
```

Comment: That works, but only because of the values of the available L1 and L2 choices in my example.  But if blue L1 had the choices (10,20,30,100) and 100 had been chosen by the user, there would be no effect when L1 was changed to red, since the "new" L2 value (red default of 100) is the same as its current value of 100.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how about:

```
shinyServer(
  function(input,output,session) {
    L1_selected <- reactiveValues(triggered=-1)

    observe({
      if (input$L1 == "red") {
        choices <- c(10, 100,200,300)
      }
      else {
        choices <- c(10,20,30)
      }

      old_L2 <- isolate(input$L2)
      updateSelectInput(session,"L2",choices=choices,selected=choices[1])
      isolate(L1_selected$triggered <- L1_selected$triggered + as.numeric(old_L2 != choices[1]))
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      if (input$L2 != "") {
        if (isolate(L1_selected$triggered)) {
          isolate(L1_selected$triggered <- L1_selected$triggered - 1)
          return()
        } else {
          plot(runif(as.numeric(input$L2)),col=input$L1)
        }
      }
    })
  })
```